# how to stop VIM changing windows security to everyone

Tags: windows, security, vim, permissions, cygwin

I am running Windows 7 64 bit with latest Cygwin.

When I edit a file the "unix" permission remain unaltered, BUT Windows Security gets set to "everyone". How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: no windows to test, but if it was true, could you look on it as a "feature" of win? ;)  I don't think it is done by vim... (just a guess)

Comment: Yes - maybe a Cygwin thing.